# Laravel commands like tinker

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, tinker

I am wondering if there's any way to run an ad-hoc command in laravel? like in tinker, but without tinker?

I want to be able to run an ad-hoc command but without using tinker ?

Example:

```
"App\Post::orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')->first()"
```

I want to run this every 5 seconds?

Comment: Check out [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling)

Comment: @linktoahref Task Scheduling (and cronjobs) are nice, but are limited to once per minute. Every 5 seconds sounds like a task for NodeJS.

Comment: I know they are limited, thats why the guys that are commenting its kinda not helping much. I know how to create cron jobs or artisan commands but nothing that I want

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write orn comands in artisan. It is very useful.

Classes are kept in `app/console`

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan

Comment: I kinda dont wanna do that! I am wondering if there is any other way ?

Comment: So you need such thing as CRON